# how to get Save & Cancel button like in Contacts?

Tags: android, android-layout

If you edit in Contacts,

- the Save & Cancel button always stays in top and placed above the
  Virtual Keyboard.
- the form elements are scrollable

I want to achieve the same behavior. I have very long form to enter and I want to make the User anytime Save/Cancel.

Please help.

Comment: check my answer , you will get what you want exactly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it by adding a footer view in your layout.example :

http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/

I achieve the same using this layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp">
            <Button "></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">
                 <RelativeLayout android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingTop="40dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingBottom="55dp">

                    <Button ></Button>

                    <Button ></Button>

                    <Button></Button>


                    <Button></Button>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
<!--for bottom bar -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:background="#ffffff">
            <Button ></Button>
            <Button ></Button>
            <Button ></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

every thing inside a linearLayout will fit above keyboard so , design layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout weightSum="X">

   <ScrollView ayout_weight="y" >
     ....
     .....
   </ScrollView>

<Layout layout_wieght="z">
       <btn save />         <btn cancel />
</layout>
<linearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code, what you need is main layout inside that

1) scrollview , in scroll view you an add layout with many views.

2) another layout with 2 buttons inside it for "save and cancel". and add style as button bar.
dont forget to add weight =1 in scrollview.

try below layout you will get what you want.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >


</ScrollView>
```

//in above scrollview add you layout with other views.

//below layou is for  button bar as you want

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/browseAddBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/browseViewBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Back" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/browseReturnBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Save" />
 </LinearLayout>
```