# How to add Save and Cancel Button to the above of keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

please see this link , this link  have image 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/attach/089583d2b50b1676/original_softKeyboard.jpg?part=4

can it is possible? if  yes  please help me!

Or 
any alternative solution ?

Comment: Those buttons are attached in the layout file (xml file used in activity) .

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is possible duplicate of  :

[how to get Save & Cancel button like in Contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982947/how-to-get-save-cancel-button-like-in-contacts/8983036#8983036)

That is a footer view :
YOu need to do something like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp">
            <Button "></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">
                 <RelativeLayout android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingTop="40dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingBottom="55dp">

                    <Button ></Button>

                    <Button ></Button>

                    <Button></Button>


                    <Button></Button>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
<!--for bottom bar -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:background="#ffffff">
            <Button ></Button>
            <Button ></Button>
            <Button ></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```